# How to configure R-3.0.1 with --enable-R-shlib

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install `R` with `--enable-R-shlib`, so that I can run `rstudio` with that version,

```
cd /mnt/data2tb/disk/soft/R-3.0.1
./configure --with-x=yes --enable-R-shlib
```

but I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../appl/dchdc.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata'
can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../appl/dchdc.o: could not read symbols: Bad value collect2: ld
returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [libR.so] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving
directory `/mnt/data2tb/disk/soft/R-3.0.1/src/main' make[2]: *** [R]
Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory
/mnt/data2tb/disk/soft/R-3.0.1/src/main make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/data2tb/disk/soft/R-3.0.1/src' make:
*** [R] Error 1
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Make sure that you're not compiling in a directory where you'd previously compiled without the `--enable-R-shlib` flag; R should be taking care of the correct compiler flags.

Comment: Dear @MartinMorgan. Your suggestion works for me! I just created another directory. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @justhalf tough because this question & R version predate the other, but the other got more attention, and the answers are somewhat different... still it's not ideal to have multiple questions on the same issue. So closing this one

Answer (score 8):

Other than changing directory as suggested by Martin Morgan in the comment, note that you can do

```
make clean
```

to clean the binaries from the previous compilation. This will save you from needing to copy the files to another folder.