# How to configure R-3.1.2 with --enable-R-shlib

Tags: r, rstudio

I had installed R-3.1.2 on Ubuntu using the commands

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz R-3.1.2.tar.gz
cd R-3.1.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

When I tried to launch RStudio I got the error

> R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?

So I went back and tried to reconfigure with

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib=yes
make
```

But I got the error

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libR.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/R-3.1.2/src/main'
make[2]: *** [R] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/R-3.1.2/src/main'
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/R-3.1.2/src'
make: *** [R] Error 1
```

When searching stack overflow, I found an answer here:
[How to configure R-3.0.1 with --enable-R-shlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561190/how-to-configure-r-3-0-1-with-enable-r-shlib)
that suggested that the problem was that I was trying to compile in a directory that I had previously compiled without the "--enable-R-shlib" option

I tried to fix the problem by using the commands

```
make uninstall
```

which gives no errors by many "Nothing to be done for `uninstall'." statements, but it did successfully uninstall R

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib=yes
```

which gives the error

```
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `src/library/base/DESCRIPTION.in'
```

then

```
make
```

which gives the same error as when I tried to make before.

Can you help me see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: `make uninstall` only undoes the `make install` step, which generally copies the files from the compilation dir to dir(s) on the system as appropriate, and puts binaries in say `/usr/bin` so they are on the path. If you wanted to clean up the dir where you did a previous compile, use `make clean` (or `make distclean`, I forget what the difference is now as far as R is concerned). You also, in general, don't want to be building in the dir which contains the R sources (which `./configure` suggests you are doing).

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Your comment qualifies as an answer. Can you post that as an answer instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`make uninstall` only undoes the `make install` step, which generally copies the files from the compilation dir to dir(s) on the system as appropriate, and puts binaries in say `/usr/bin` so they are on the path. If you wanted to clean up the dir where you did a previous compile, use `make clean` (or `make distclean`, I forget what the difference is now as far as R is concerned but convention is that it should return the build dir to pre-configure, pre-build state.).

You also, in general, don't want to be building in the dir which contains the R sources (which `./configure` suggests you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

`make clean` is the way to go; here to add some further words of clarification on what's going on.

You attempted to build R with the wrong options (i.e., without using `--enable-R-shlib` as is required to use it with RStudio), and in the process did either a full or a partial build of R.

Your error message says the issue arose in `./src/main`, where the earlier `make` compiled the `.c` files there into the `.o` files. When you re-run `make` after re-`./configure`-ing with the right options, it sees those `.o` files and says "I don't need to re-compile the `.c` files here, `.o` files already exist" and attempts to proceed.

However, those `.o` files were compiled under a different configuration, so they are "stale" in that sense -- `make clean` removes those `.o` files (as well as any other artefacts of the earlier build that are now obsolete).

There may be a more minimal way of resetting your build (`make clean` removes *all* built files from the earlier `make`, but maybe only some subset of those is required), but this would probably depend on what exactly is the difference between the earlier `./configure` options and the new ones, and you're apt to spend more time tinkering than it would take to just do a clean build (personally, I gave up after removing all the `./src/main/*.o` files wasn't enough).