# Install specific version of R and open in RStudio (Linux Mint)

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

My question is similar to this one:

[How to configure R-3.1.2 with --enable-R-shlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096239/how-to-configure-r-3-1-2-with-enable-r-shlib)

I would like to install a specific version of R and open it in RStudio.
I unzipped the tar file to `/home/sewo/Downloads/R-3.0.3`.
In this folder I ran

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Furthermore, I copied the following line

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/home/sewo/Downloads/R-3.0.3/bin/R
```

into the file `~/.profile` what is supposed to make sure that RStudio finds this R installation (This information is from https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R .)
When I then try to start RStudio, the following error message occurs:

> R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is
>   a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?

So my plan is to uninstall R and re-install with the `--enable-R-shlib` option. I tried:

```
make uninstall 
make clean
make distclean
```

Then I try to re-install by:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/R/3.0.3 --enable-R-shlib
```

but get the error

```
cannot find input file: `src/library/base/DESCRIPTION.in'
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you start with a freshly unpacked R tarball? AFAIK `--enable-R-shlib` does not work reliably in a directory where `configure` ran before without this option.

Comment: Yes, started over with a new download. Then it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Feel free to answer your own question.