# How to configure R-3.3.2 with --enable-R-shlib on RHEL7 EC2

Tags: r, rhel7

My question relates to [How to configure R-3.0.1 with --enable-R-shlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561190/how-to-configure-r-3-0-1-with-enable-r-shlib). I'm getting the same error, but I'm not following what is meant by "Make sure that you're not compiling in a directory where you'd previously compiled without the `--enable-R-shlib` flag". I am not compiling in a directory where I previously compiled without the `--enable-R-shlib` flag. I'm doing the following on a RHEL7 EC2 instance:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.3.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf R-3.3.2.tar.gz
cd R-3.3.2
./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no --enable-R-shlib
make
```

That's when I get the error shown in the link to the other post. If I exclude `--enable-R-shlib` then `make` runs fine. However, I then run into problems when trying to install RStudio later.

Comment: Not sure, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096239/how-to-configure-r-3-1-2-with-enable-r-shlib?noredirect=1&lq=1) might help?

Comment: I saw that too. Same problem, except it seems like they only had an error when trying to configure R with `--enable-R-shlib` after they had already tried to do so without it. In my case I never tried to configure R without it.

Comment: Once again, I am not particularly expert at this, so my comments may be unhelpful, but since no one else is responding I thought I would try.  Have you tried doing an uninstall just to make 100% sure you hadn't previously installed it and didn't remember?  If you ran the command without `--enable-R-shlib` that would mean you had previously installed in that directory and could be the problem.

Comment: Yep, I created a new instance and only tried to install with `--enable-R-shlib`. Still same problem.

Comment: Got it to work following this site: http://datascience-enthusiast.com/Hadoop/SparkR_on_HDP_AWS_EC2.html. Not sure what was wrong the first time.